# Issues with html code

Tags: xss, html

I am just wondering if this HTML code is vulnerable/unsecure at all and if so, why?. Thank you. I am only beginning to learn about HTML so that is the reason for the question.

```
<form method="post" action="Login_Account.php">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

This code is a standard form, there is not much secure or insecure about it.

Some enterprise policies will require it to include a flag to stop browsers from auto completing, but if you do not need that it is better to leave it off.

There seems to be no anti-CSRF token in this form, this seems to be a problem. Other than that make sure it is hosted on https and the server side handling the input is secure.

You might also want to add some headers against frame inclusion and set a content security policy to turn off or limit scripting.